# How to cancel one function for object.prototypes javascript

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype

http://codepen.io/haikudoichi/pen/EazdyL

What is supposed to happen is when I click on a created object, it should disappear and a new one should not be made if it's in the boundaries of the old one. If I click elsewhere, then it's supposed to make a new object.

What's actually happening is that a new object is made in place of the old one.

I'm thinking my

```
var noDraw = false;
```

as a sort of flag would help but the method I tried did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rectangle.prototype.hit isn't returning anything, which is causing the getHit to never return anything, thereby setting hit = null in handleMouseDown.

Instead of

```
flag = true;
this.width = 0;
this.height = 0;
```

do

```
this.width = 0;
this.height = 0;
return true;
```